# To display spaces between text of multiline textbox in label

Tags: c#, .net, html

Prefered output -

```
Hi
Hello
U            There...
```

Current output -

```
Hi Hello U there...
```

Using replace method with `<br/>` tags works only for new line. However I need to retain the space between U and There.

Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Comment: @Jon ah you beat me to the edit! :)

Comment: @jv42 - jon can beat any one so..............he is the fastest

Comment: @Pranay - I know I know, Jon is so fast he edits the questions before they are asked! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `&nbsp;` for each space?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Jon Skeet answer  replace space by &nbsp using regular expression.

```
string s1 = "He saw   a cute\tdog.";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\s+");
string s3 = r.Replace(s1, "&nbsp;");
```

Comment: I think your should replace would go like this `string s3 = r.Replace(s1, "&nbsp;");`

Answer (score 0):

In html just add
null 
eg:

```
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
<optgroup >// get a space between 
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: i was answer before edit the question some one modified the question so dont put negative to question dudes...if not satisfied

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sos = "";
        if (TextBox1.Text == sos)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "00";
        }
        char opo = TextBox1.Text[0];
        char opo1 = TextBox1.Text[1];
        Label1.Text = (opo + " " + opo1);

    }
```

input to texbox text = 23
autput to Label = 2 3